Is a homotopy long exact sequence for a pair always isomorphic to a long exact sequence coming from a fibration

My question was already raised a couple years ago (see here). But it wasn't really answered so I am trying my luck again. 
Given a fibration $F\to E\to B$ we know that it's long exact sequence is isomorphic, via maps of pairs, to the long exact sequence of $(E, F)$. Now given a pair $(X,A)$ can we find a fibration $F_A\to E_X\to B$ such that the two homotopy long exact sequences are isomorphic via maps of pairs? 
My motivation for this question is to use the technology of Puppe fiber sequences to study the long exact sequence of a pair. 
Thank you so much in advance for your help.

The answer is no, and not even in "nice" cases. One obstruction is that a fibration comes not just with a long exact sequence in homotopy groups, but also with an (albeit more complicated) gadget to compute the associated co/homology groups, namely the Serre spectral sequence. Since the maps you need for an isomorphism of long exact sequences are all weak equivalences by definition, the co/homology of $F_A$ and $E_X$ is already fully determined and we've a got shot at finding a counterexample.
...and that's what I'm going to do. Concretely, I will show that the long exact sequence for the (CW!) pairs $\newcommand{\CP}{\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}}(\CP^\infty, \CP^n)$ cannot be obtained from a fibration. To this end, assume that there is a fibration $F \to E \to B$ such that there are weak equivalences $F \to \CP^n$, $E \to \CP^\infty$, and $(B, b_0) \simeq_w (E, F) \to (\CP^\infty, \CP^n)$ for some choice of basepoint $b \in B$ inducing an isomorphism of long exact sequences in homotopy groups.
Consider now the Serre spectral sequence
$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
    E_2^{*, *} = H^*(B; H^*(\CP^n)) \cong H^*(B) \otimes \Z[x] / x^{n + 1} \Rightarrow H^*(\CP^\infty) \cong \Z[y]
$$
for $x$ and $y$ generators in degree 2. It is not difficult to compute the $E_2$-page fully: Since $(\CP^\infty, \CP^n)$ is $(2n + 1)$-connected with $\pi_{2n + 2}(\CP^\infty, \CP^n) \cong \Z$, the first non-zero entry in positive degree on the horizontal axis is $E_2^{2n + 2, 0} \cong \Z$, which is generated by some $z$. On the other hand, the vertical axis contains the cohomology of $\CP^n$, so we see that $E_2^{2n + 2, 2k} \cong \Z$ for all $0 \leq k \leq n$, with these groups generated by $y, yx, y x^2, \ldots, y x^n$. But $d_r(x) = d_r(y) = 0$ for all $r$, so these elements already form infinite cycles. This accounts for the convergence to $H^m(\CP^\infty)$ in the range $2n + 2 \leq m \leq 4n + 2$, so the next non-zero cohomology group of $B$ has to be $H^{4n + 4}(B) \cong \Z$. Continuing this pattern, we find that $H^{2k(n + 1)}(B) \cong \Z$ for all $k \geq 0$ with all other groups 0.
...but this is a contradiction: After all, I have a (weak) equivalence of pairs $(B, b_0) \simeq_w (\CP^\infty, \CP^n)$ and therefore an isomorphism $\tilde{H}^*(B) \cong H^*(\CP^\infty, \CP^n) \cong \tilde{H}^*(\CP^\infty / \CP^n)$ and this latter group is non-zero in all even degrees $\geq 2n + 2$.

wow this is an amazing answer, thank you so much. A clear answer, with motivation and fully worked out answer!!!
